# Can't compile java in oracle: badly formed source

Tags: java, oracle

I'm executing the following code in Navicat:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "util"
AS
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class util extends Object
{
    public static String exec(String cmd)
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        return "";
    }
}
```

And it fails with:

```
ORA-29536: badly formed source: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 16.
Was expecting:
    ";" ...
    
, Time: 0.059000s
```

The source code compiles correctly with javac, why won't it work in Oracle19?

Comment: The function ought to `throw` an `IOException` (or have a `try`/`catch` block). You don't need to `import java.lang.*;` or `extends Object` and you should name the classes you are importing (i.e. `java.io.IOException`) rather than importing using wildcards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile it you get the exception:

```
ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
util:7: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                                     ^

1 error
```

You can fix that (and a few other minor things that don't affect compilation but aren't necessary to include, and you probably don't want to use a quoted identifier):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED util
AS
import java.io.IOException;

public class Util
{
    public static String exec(String cmd) throws IOException
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Then it compiles [Oracle 18 db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ee68034a96933f2d42b9b2beda3e90e2).

*Note: this function is a huge security issue for your database and you probably should find an alternative solution rather than allowing arbitrary code execution.*